# VBA if the first 6 characters in a Cell DO NOT equal 01/01/ then

Tags: string, vba, excel, colors

I hope you can help. I have a piece of code below and it is does not seem to be working correctly

What I want the code to do is this

if the **first 6 characters** of any cell in the entire length of Column L does not contain 01/01/ then highlight that cell with interior color 27

At the moment as you can see in Screen Shot 1 every cell in Column L is highlighted with interior color 27 , only Cell L2 and L5 should be colored.

My Code is below can it be amended to only highlight the cells that do not contain 01/01/ as the first 6 Characters in Column L

**> PS the Conditional formatting approach is not an option**

As always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Screen Shot 1
[image]

MY CODE

```
Sub Colour_If()
    RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each n In Range("L2:L" & RowCount)
        n = Left(n, 6)
        If n <> "01/01/" Then
        Range("L2:L" & RowCount).Interior.ColorIndex = 24

        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: Your problem is here: `Range("L2:L" & RowCount).Interior.ColorIndex = 24`. As soon as it meets the condition once you are colouring the entire column. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with Dates it can get a little tricky, I've used the `Like` operator with the wild-card `*`, and read the `Text` property of the cell.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Colour_If()

    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim n As Range

    ' always define your worksheet, don't rely on ActiveSheet
    With Worksheets("YourSheetName") '<-- modify to your sheet's name
        RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each n In .Range("L2:L" & RowCount)
            If Not n.Text Like "01/01/*" Then ' check that the first 6 characters do not start with "01/01/"
                n.Interior.ColorIndex = 24
            End If
        Next n
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: :-) Thank you once again Shai. This works perfectly :-) Much respect from Dublin :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
Sub Colour_If()

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lRow
If Left(Cells(i, 12), 6) <> "01/01/" Then
Cells(i, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
Else
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: 12 refers to column "L". i is the row number. It will go through each row until the last row with data in column L.

Comment: To be more explicit, @ the top of the code under sub you can add `Dim lRow as Long` and `Dim i as Long`.

Comment: Hi KoderM16 Thank you for taking the time to respond. It is greatly appreciated. I have accepted Shai's answer as it works and was first to respond. Thank you again for the support :-) I hope you have a great day.

Comment: @PhilipConnell cool buddy. Glad you got the assistance you needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Colour_If()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim RowCount as Long
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To RowCount
        With sht
            n = Left(.Cells(i, 12).Value, 6)
            If n <> "01/01/" Then
                .Cells(i, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
            Else
                .Cells(i, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. UGP thank you so much for taking the time to respond. Your code works perfectly but Shai was there first and has helped me in the past. Thank you again :-) and I wish you a great day :-)